# Firestore Offline Promise Handling?

Tags: firebase, promise, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps

I have been scouring the [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and the [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/offline-data.md) docs looking for any information regarding how firebase/angularfire handles it's write promises when my progressive web app is offline.

The problem is that all of my promises returned from the batch writes are not being resolved (or rejected), so should I be assuming that all promises made offline will be resolved? If so, am I correct in saying I should rather be handling redirects and success messages before the promise is resolved?

Besides my unresolved firebase promises, the offline mode seems to work well. It correctly changes data in various places throughout many collections and documents, and the changes are displayed correctly in the web app.

Once returning to online mode, the relevant changes are made to the database and my pending promises all seem to get resolved at once.

Is this expected behaviour? And if it is what would the correct way about handling success/error messages and redirects be (if they were previously handled in the promise *then* and *catch*)

Comment: Yes, AngularFire builds on the firebase library - and that already does it.

Comment: What you see is indeed the expected behavior. The correct way to handle success/error depends on your use-case and the needs of your app, making it impossible for us to say anything definitive. But if you have a specific piece of code that you're struggling with, update your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can have a look.

Comment: I would like to see some real life examples for this, it's really confusing at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore promises (and completion handlers on other platforms) indeed resolve/reject when the write operation has been committed/rejected on the server. So what you see is indeed the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply! Just watched your ask firebase interview. Pretty awesome to see you guys so happy to help us out. Thanks again